# ObjectBox Database sharing between main app and its extension

Tags: ios, swift, database-migration, objectbox, data-sharing

I was trying to share the Objectbox created database between the app and its extension.
I used the below code to share the database between the app and its extension.

```
static func storeURL() -> URL {
        guard let fileContainer = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "AppGroupName") else {
            fatalError("Shared file container could not be created.")
        }

        return fileContainer.appendingPathComponent("\(databaseName)")
    }
```

The app is working fine when the app is running in foreground. When the app goes to the background then the app is crashing. When I remove the above code and used the below code

```
let appSupport = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                     in: .userDomainMask,
                                                     appropriateFor: nil,
                                                     create: true)
                                                     .appendingPathComponent(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
        let directory = appSupport.appendingPathComponent(databaseName)
```

The app does not crash and started working fine without Database sharing.

Note: If we ignore this crash, I was able to use the database from the app and its extension.

Comment: Can you post details of "the app is crashing", e.g. crash logs/stacks? If you think it's a bug, please use the issue tracker on GitHub.

Comment: I added the issue on git of objectbox with all detail. Please check.
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-swift/issues/61